# Tracker PDU Android Parsing

Tags: android, sms, hex, pdu

I am receiving a PDU string from tracker. And i want to parse that and get information in that string.

```
     0791293303501320040c91293356316511000031504241341402a0300799002b0918050d0310a806b392ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

But the Problem is that i am unable to parse that. I had tried many Methods on Google but nothing works. Then i tried to decode this string via [online decoder](http://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/online-sms-pdu-decoder/) But that didnt generate a desired output for that. 
**And Kind of help will be highly appropriated, I am stucked in that problem from last 2 days.**
*Is any thing wrong with that pdu ? 
And good method to Parse that ?*

Answer (score 0):

Standard SMS PDUs are defined in the 3GPP specification 27.005, available [here.](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm)
Look at section 2.5.2.6 Short Message Data.
Translate your PDU into binary, divide it into bytes (octets), and match it against the spec.